# Trying to use npm start

Tags: node.js, git-bash

Trying to use npm start but think there is an issue with my package json:

```
{
  "name": "juggling-licence-prototype",
  "version": "1.0.0",
 "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": ""
}
```

Comment: Why do you "*think there is an issue with [your] package json*"?

Comment: $ npm start
npm ERR! file C:\Users\George\Documents\projects\juggling-licence-prototype\package.json
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse json
npm ERR! JSON.parse Unexpected token , in JSON at position 72 while parsing near '... "1.0.0", "index.js",
npm ERR! JSON.parse   "scripts": {
npm ERR! JSON.parse    ...'
npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! JSON.parse package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.

Answer (score 3):

You need to ad a comma (,) between your scripts like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
```

Or you could simple delete the `test` script since it's only some example from npm. To use the `start` script, the following would be enough:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

In the package.json file you are missing "main".
It should be `"main":"index.js"`
not just `"index.js"`

Comment: i've also tried this, but i get a different error if i include this